# Pass an array from ajax call with data:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url : ROOT_PATH + "/requirements/" + req_id + "/edit",
    type : "get", 
    data : "req_info=" + req_info,
    success : function(data) {

        $("#Requirements_div").html(data);
        $("#Requirements_div").show();
        $(".new_req_link").attr("data-a",project_id);

    }
});
```

How to pass an array using data: . I mean what if req_info is an array ?

I want to pass an array from the ajax call to the controller using the 'data' attribute.

EDIT:

```
var arr = new Array();
        $('#Testpoints_div input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            arr.push($(this).text());

        });

$.ajax({
            url : ROOT_PATH + "/requirements/"+req_id+"/edit",
            type : "get", 
            data : {req_info : req_info , checked_boxes: arr},
            success : function(data) {

                alert("success")


            }
        });
```

Controller code:

```
 @checked_boxes = params[:checked_boxes]


    @checked_boxes.each do |checkbox|
      logger.info "checkbox: #{checkbox}"
    end
```

checkbox  value is empty .

Comment: Could you be more clear? Not sure what the problem is?

Comment: @tymeJV    I want to pass an array from the ajax call to the controller using the 'data' attribute.

Comment: Try `data: {req_info : req_info},`

Comment: @tymeJV I also want to send a variable along with this array.how do we that ?

Comment: Add another key/value pair: `data: {req_info : req_info, someVar : variable}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the data along as an object:

```
$.ajax({
    url : ROOT_PATH + "/requirements/" + req_id + "/edit",
    type : "get", 
    data : {req_info : req_info, someVar : variable}
    success : function(data) {
       ....
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass JSON object to `data` on $.ajax call. It will be a {key:value} pair and then in value you can pass Array as well. See the [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).